# How to enable queue_log on the embedded Asterisk of a Yeastar MyPBX?

Tags: asterisk, pbx

I have an old PBX from Yeastar that contains an instance of Asterisk 1.6.2.6.
How can I enable the `queue_log` setting and have it persist across reboots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to enable SSH access from the web interface (System / LAN settings / Enable SSH).
Then log into the MyPBX and create the file `/persistent/custom-cfg/logger_custom.conf` with the following content:

```
[general]
queue_log = yes
; enable log rotation and removal of the archived file to avoid filling up the partition
rotatestrategy = sequential
exec_after_rotate = rm ${filename}
```

Finally, reboot the PBX:
`asterisk -rx 'core restart gracefully'`